# What's the difference between the lifted representation and the grounded representation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning, pddl

What's the difference between those two representations of a planning problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Grounded representation** restricts the planning rules to propositional logic: no variables, simple condition => effect rules.

**Lifted representation** extends this to simple FOPC (first-order predicate calculus), in which you get variables, predicates (straightforward status functions), and simple operations (such as negation).

Is that enough of a partition for your purposes?

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Can you put a example?

Comment: If you search out the topic on line, you will find examples, with a greater range and more detail than one example would add here.  This is why Stack Overflow does not extend into tutorial presentations.